# VBA in excel move value between columns

Tags: vba, loops, excel, conditional-statements

I have excel file with filled two columns. First, includes numbers, second letter. I want to fill third column by letter with condition:
IF the same number has "A" in any cells in second colum THEN fill with the letter A every cells for this number in third column
ELSEIF "B" THEN B in third column...
 Priority A>B>C>D

Comment: Try COUNTIF function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this

```
Sub test()
    Dim Dic As Object: Set Dic = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    Dim Cl As Range, i&
    i = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    For Each Cl In ActiveSheet.Range("A1:A" & i)
        If Not Dic.exists(Cl.Value & Cl.Offset(, 1).Value) Then
            Dic.Add (Cl.Value & Cl.Offset(, 1).Value), Cl.Row
        End If
    Next
    For Each Cl In ActiveSheet.Range("A1:A" & i)
        If Dic.exists(Cl.Value & "A") Then
            Cl.Offset(, 2).Value = "A"
        ElseIf Dic.exists(Cl.Value & "B") Then
            Cl.Offset(, 2).Value = "B"
        ElseIf Dic.exists(Cl.Value & "C") Then
            Cl.Offset(, 2).Value = "C"
        ElseIf Dic.exists(Cl.Value & "D") Then
            Cl.Offset(, 2).Value = "D"
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

output result is

[image]

## updated against new requirements

use this

```
Sub test()
    Dim Dic As Object: Set Dic = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    Dim Cl As Range, i&, key As Variant
    i = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    For Each Cl In ActiveSheet.Range("A1:A" & i)
        If Not Dic.exists(Cl.Value & Cl.Offset(, 1).Value) Then
            Dic.Add (Cl.Value & Cl.Offset(, 1).Value), Cl.Row
        End If
    Next
    For Each Cl In ActiveSheet.Range("A1:A" & i)
        For Each key In Dic
            If UCase(key) Like Cl.Value & "*A*" Then
                Cl.Offset(, 2).Value = Mid(key, 2, 100)
                Exit For
            End If
        Next
        If Cl.Offset(, 2).Value = Empty Then
            For Each key In Dic
                If UCase(key) Like Cl.Value & "*B*" Then
                    Cl.Offset(, 2).Value = Mid(key, 2, 100)
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next
        End If
        If Cl.Offset(, 2).Value = Empty Then
            For Each key In Dic
                If UCase(key) Like Cl.Value & "*C*" Then
                    Cl.Offset(, 2).Value = Mid(key, 2, 100)
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next
        End If
        If Cl.Offset(, 2).Value = Empty Then
            For Each key In Dic
                If UCase(key) Like Cl.Value & "*D*" Then
                    Cl.Offset(, 2).Value = Mid(key, 2, 100)
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

output result

[image]

Comment: Perfect, it's exactly what I need but i've another question. What if in column "B" will be strings for example ABA, BBB, CCC etc. And want to the same results, if ABA contains "A" then ABA. How to change this "exists" method ?

Comment: I mean similar situation but column  "B" contains instead single letters (A,B,C,D)  sentence for example "My name is mac". If in column B is "name is" fill column "C"

Comment: @mac If I understand correctly, then use something like this (see updated post). 'Exists' in this case not applicable

Comment: Yes, thank you very much. I'm totally beginner in VBA and you're really helpfully for me

Answer (score 0):

If you can use formula instead of VBA following formula would do the job:

```
=IF(COUNTIFS(A:A,A2,B:B,"A")>0,"A",IF(COUNTIFS(A:A,A2,B:B,"B")>0,"B",IF(COUNTIFS(A:A,A2,B:B,"C")>0,"C","D")))
```

in this formula `COUNTIF` function is combining 2 criterias and counting if these criterias meet or not, then `IF` functions are inputting related letter to the cell.